# How to set list<String> in body http.post

Tags: flutter, dart

in postman body:

```
id:2
images[]:image1 base64
image[]:image2 base64
```

how to set body to send request?

this my code

```
  var uri = 'url';
  var images = List<String>();
  Map data = {
    'id': id,
    'images[]' : images,
  };

  var body = json.encode(data);
  final response = await http.post(uri, body: body);
  print("${response.statusCode}");
  print("${response.body}");
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Model.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
```

response is failed

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you facing any specific issue?

Comment: in post man i have success, but with code response is failed, what wrong with mycode?

Comment: what type of error are you getting? Is it possible that you forgot to set Headers (Bearer and such)?

Comment: no header in my rest API,no error, but i have failed request response.

Comment: it turns out my rest api cannot accept json object

Comment: I think posting the error might help to resolve or make better suggestions. Please add error log and more details of exact problem.

Comment: What is in images[]? Are there the names of the images or base64 of the images?